# sorting std vector of files names with numbers

Tags: c++, std

Im using `std::vector<std::string>` which conatin files names with the same extension.
The vector look like:

```
"A_1.x"
"A_2.x"
"A_3.x"
```

until ~1100.
When perform `sort()` on the vector Im getting the following:

```
A_1.x,A_10.x,A_100.x,A_1000.x,A_1001.x ....
```

instead of

```
A_1.x,A_2.x,A_3.x,A_4.x,A_5.x ....
```

How can I use sort to get the desire result?
*Im not using C++ 11

Comment: pass a comparison function to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: can you explain please? @UnholySheep

Comment: `std::sort` has an overload that takes a comparison function, which allows you to specify how you want the elements to be sorted - see the link in my previous comment for more information

Comment: Unfortunate double-tagging over there. :(